# what does 'x' symbolise in the Python language, particularly in 'for' statements?

Tags: python

I'm currently learning Python, and am starting to get confused by the use of letters, etc.

```
tup = [1,2,3,4,5]
for t in tup:
     print(t)
```

Now, I could change 'tup' to 'mytuple' or 'my_list_of_numbers'.
Am I right in thinking that the next line is saying "call tup t and then we will just print t, instead of writing print tup"?

I'm struggling to understand the differences between people writing for X or for T or for Y in tup or mylist etc.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: As long as you're consistent, you can use any [valid identifier](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers). X, T, Y, banana, supercalifragilisticexpialidocious, ...whatever.

Comment: @amnesia180 Nope, "call tup t" is what `t = tup` does; `for t in tup:` means "make t equal to each item in tup in turn" (so that `print(t)` prints `tup[0]`, then `tup[1]` etc.)

Comment: Names are arbitrary (excluding reserved words), but `for t in tup:` means "take each element of `tup` in turn, call it `t`, and execute the indented lines".  Note that in the example, `tup` is a list, not a tuple; names are arbitrary, but that means they can also be misleading.

Comment: It seems like you are not familiar with what `for` actually does. Try to read [this section](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) of the documentation and see if it clears things up.

Answer (score 0):

The for in syntax is creating an [iterator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator) over the data structure.

So when you're using :

```
for x in iterable_object : 
    # Do something with x (ex : print(x))
```

x will take every value contained in iterable_object so in your example 1 then 2 then 3 then 4 then 5.

This syntax is equivalent to :

```
for i in range(len(iterable_object)) : 
    print(iterable_object[i])
    # Do something with iterable_object[i]
```

It's a shortcut, like syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 0):

`For` loop iterates through [iterable objects](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator).

The code block is executed for each member of the iterable, or sequence.

The actual syntax is:

```
for variable in sequence:
    # code
```

In Python `For` doesn't require indexing variable inizialization, you just declare it in the statement.

In your example `tup` is your iterable object, and `t` is the variable in wich current element of the iterable is stored during iteration.

Answer (score -1):

> At first lets consider there no x, y or z just nothing in this
>   universe. 
>  You and I both know only Human Language.

**Now lets look at two cases written in pure English language**

---

*case 1:* Now if I give you a packet of buscuit and say:

```
open the packet and eat each buscuit one by one
```

*case 2:* and again give you a packet of buscuit and say:

```
for each buscuit in packet
        eat it
```

*desition:* Both the cases are same by natural human expression.

**Now lets say the same words in the language of Pythons**

---

First we consider that there is an array named buscuit_packet
buscuit_packet = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

 
as pythons don't eat buscuits we are simply gonna print them

```
buscuit_packet = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

for each in buscuit_packet:
    print(each)


# here the word 'each' refers to one single buscuit we take and after using it
# we take the next one, it loops and the next one, it loops agian...
# until the last buscuit which is buscuit number 10 in our case and 
# alas after eating buscuit no. 10 the loop terminates

# ps. a human will probably eat(each)
```

The output to this code will be:


1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

pure image output:

[checkout the image of console output and feel the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlzqU.png)